# JavaBeans: how to have private data?

Tags: java, javabeans, getter-setter

As per the JavaBeans specification, all member variables of a class must have public getter and setter methods. However, some data is logically part of the internal working of the class and should not be exposed to the user of a Bean. What is the correct way to have truly private data members?

One way I came up with was to have a **private** method, like getValueX(), which just returns the value X. Then, you can use this in place of the value of variable X. But this only allows retrieval, not update. What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Just don't declare any getters and setters but use the private field for access.

Comment: If you want to restrict access to a private field omit the corresponding setter (read only) or getter (write only). If you omit both the field is for internal use only. Alternatively change the visibility of the getter and/or setter to `private`, e.g. if you want to have logic in them.

Comment: @Thomas: wouldn't that violate the JavaBeans specification?

Comment: @f1sh: I do understand the concept of private member variables, but as far as I have researched, private member variables of a JavaBean must have getter and setter methods according to Oracle's specification.

Comment: If I recall, JavaBeans are meant to be a container for data.  Meaning it should do very little or no logic to it's fields.  If you're looking to represent some kind of data structure or data that is to be heavily operated on, then you could consider making the bean to hold the data, and another object which accepts the bean to perform operations on.

Comment: @JulianCleary: while i want to agree with you, there are a lot of definitions - including the ones given on this site - that state a JavaBean is a component, meaning a building block of an application. Tutorials also implement examples where the Bean itself has behaviour (for example, it is a GUI-object such as an Applet or an form window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the original [JavaBeans Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/):

> **8.5 Design Patterns for Methods**
>
> By default, we assume that all public methods of a Java Bean should be exposed as external methods within
> the component environment for access by other components or by
> scripting languages.

Thus, it follows that if you have a class with fields that have only private accessors and mutators, they would be excluded from the introspection (by default) and that class can still technically represent a "Java Bean" since its properties with public accessors and mutators satisfy the JavaBeans specification.

Having said that, I believe that it is better to access private fields directly in your implementation, rather than providing private setters and getters for them.

Comment: I agree with your second point completely, it's the better way. But my question is, if you're allowed to ignore the getter and setter restriction, why add them in the specification at all?